# How to create a relative path for this HTML element in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have an HTML element I am trying to click on, in an Angular grid.
When I use Developer Tools to copy the XPath I end up with a massively long XPath. This does work, however I would like to make it a relative path as this is the only select dropdown on the page.

See HTML and working (but inefficient XPapth below).

```
 <input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" readonly="" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false">
```

and XPath is

```
//*[@id='content-container']/inv-sidebar-layout-content/ng-component/ng-component/section/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[1]/article/inv-people-tabs/inv-vertical-tabs-list/div[2]/div/inv-tab[4]/div/inv-grid/div/div/div[2]/dx-data-grid/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following xpath.

```
//input[@class='dx-texteditor-input']
```

Comment: That's the one. Thanks very much!